# nested connected react-redux v6 component not finding store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This following issues was marked as resolved on the reduxjs/react-redux issues page, but there doesn't seem to be a resolution. [Could not find "store" in either the context or props](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/57)

In particular, I have the [same question as Andrew Ray](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/57#issuecomment-180121722), which is why isn't the store getting passed to nested connected components?

Comment: please include the important content from each link

Comment: Hi, I'm a Redux maintainer, and the one who locked that issue.  Note that the prior questions in that thread are several years old.  [React-Redux v6 just came out](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v6.0.0), and it has [a very different internal implementation](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/#v6-0).  In order to figure out what's happening, we need you to show your store and React tree setup, and how you're connecting and using your components.